# I have mentioned the Plugins in YAML file but still getting issues in Xcode

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image][image]
I am getting plugin not found error in Xcode.

Comment: Can you show us your Podfile, and see if in showInFinder you do find the same files?

Comment: # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Runner' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner


end

Comment: Would you mind provide a reproducible code or git repo, so I can have a build with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter build ios` and then open it in xcode

Comment: Getting this error:     Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/callidustechnosystems/Desktop/AndroidProjects/RAMA/Flutter/Projects/CommunityMobileApp/ios/Ru
    nner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: fatal error: 'file_picker/FilePickerPlugin.h' file not found
    #import <file_picker/FilePickerPlugin.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description